# Integral calculation for eigenvalues

Tags: integration, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-operators

I am trying to solve the following integral
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}{e^{ik\cos\left(\theta-\varphi\right)}\cos\left(n\theta\right)}d\theta\right|^2 d\varphi},\ \ n=0,1,2,.......$
which gives the eigenvalues of some integral operator. Obviously the calculation will be done
numerically with MATLAB but my problem is the absolute value which is outside of the
integral. Can anyone help?

Comment: hint: $|A|^2 = AA^{*}$

Comment: I think that this makes it even more complicated!

Comment: Maybe explain when do you mean by "my problem is...", and I might be able to help more.

Comment: I can't implement it in MATLAB because the absolute value is "outside" of the integral with respect to $\theta$

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: If the absolute value is "inside" then i can use the double integral function, but since it is "outside" i can't find a way of doing it.

Comment: Does matlab have a triple integral? If so, use the hint